# maven dependency clash

Tags: maven-2

In my project, there are 2 libraries, each of which depend on the XML parsing class java.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory. Each of these libraries reference the file from different jar (one gets it from a jar called xmlParserAPIs while another gets it from xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar). Unfortunately there are different versions of the class in each of these files so I am seeing runtime errors, depending on the order they are loaded. Both of these xml jars are transitive dependencies of 3rd party libraries. Is there a good way to handle this conflict?

edit: I'm not sure if it makes a difference on how to handle the problem but this only happens in testing because one of the dependencies is in the test scope.

thanks,
jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (...) Unfortunately there are different versions of the class in each of these files so I am seeing runtime errors, depending on the order they are loaded.

In theory, `xml-apis.jar` and `xmlParserAPIs.jar` (from xerces2-j) are the **same JARs** but with different names, `xmlParserAPIs.jar` being deprecated for years (see [this message](http://markmail.org/thread/hj6kdvgsvxtqmhtp) and [this one](http://markmail.org/message/pcolq7lt2wekkbmu)).

If your dependencies relies on different and incompatible versions of `xml-apis.jar`, I would say that these dependencies are mutually exclusive, in other words incompatible, at least for the versions you're using. The only solution would be to find versions with a converging dependency.

In case they could use compatible versions, use a dependency [exclusion](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) for `xmlParserAPIs.jar` to use `xml-api.jar` only.

> I'm not sure if it makes a difference on how to handle the problem but this only happens in testing because one of the dependencies is in the test scope.

No, this just explains why you don't get the problem at runtime (because the `test` scoped is not on the classpath then and, obviously, doesn't conflict).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I have conflicts with xml libraries in 2 other libs. If I exclude both the xmlParserAPIs and xml-apis from the jars and just let the jre provide those, everything works well. Is this an unsafe thing to do? And should I be added a system scoped dependency for java.xml.parsers? Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff 1. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to analyze your dependencies. 2. If it works with the parser of the JRE, then just exclude the dependencies. 3. I tend to avoid `system` scoped dependencies (more troubles than benefits in my opinion).