# What is the spring-boot-configuration-processor ? Why do people exclude libraries from it? Why is it invisible in dependency tree?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, gradle

## Introduction

So I noticed the following line in the gradle file of the jhipster project:

```
annotationProcessor ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor") {
        exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'
    }
```

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gradle/blob/9e9c3db8f3bedba4b1efd85ecb6ff3f12a5f596a/build.gradle#L230

We also used the same configuration in Maven for another project to solve the following problem: [Maven transient dependency (library/jar vaadin json) is not being excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53260385/1688441)

## Questions

And now I have the following questions:

- What does the spring-boot-configuration-processor dependency do?
- Why is it necessary to sometimes exclude dependencies from the processor?
- Why doesn't the processor necessarily appear in the mvn-dependency tree?
- Why are exclusions used with processor in situations where it's very difficult to exclude a dependency?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

`spring-boot-configuration-processor` is an annotation processor that generates metadata about classes in your application that are annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`. This metadata is used by your IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, or NetBeans) to provide auto-completion and documentation for the properties when editing `application.properties` and `application.yaml` files. You can learn a bit more about it in the [relevant section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata.annotation-processor) of Spring Boot's reference documentation.

Since Spring Boot 1.5.10, the exclusion is no longer necessary as `com.vaadin.external.google:android-json` is no longer a dependency of `spring-boot-configuration-processor`.

Answer (score 13):

> What does the spring-boot-configuration-processor dependency do?

It [scans the libraries in the build and sees what properties they use](https://jakubstas.com/configuration-meta-data-in-spring-boot/#.XA53bhP7SL8) so as to [inform the IDE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html)

> Why is it necessary to sometimes exclude dependencies from the processor?

Maven libraries can clash sometimes - the one you reference was excluded by JHipster because [it led to errors when on the classpath together with another library in JHipster's dependencies](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/9e36776721af1b3cd5f3adbcffbba6696612db53)

> Why doesn't the processor necessarily appear in the mvn dependency:tree?

It does for me on the `jhipster-sample-app`. Presumably you're referring to the [comment on the linked issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260385/maven-transient-dependency-library-jar-vaadin-json-is-not-being-excluded#comment93414598_53260385) stating that the `android-json` library isn't in the tree. I've asked there about that.

> Why are exclusions used with processor in situations where it's very difficult to exclude a dependency?

This is a [dependency clash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190216/maven-dependency-clash) issue like any other really, it just happens that the processor is bringing in the key dependency (or rather was, as @[Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) points out `com.vaadin.external.google:android-json` is no longer used by the processor)

Comment: This sounds like it is a Dev-only dependency. if it is only supporting IDE features, I should mark it with "provided" scope?
 Why didn't spring boot initializr tool do that while generating the project?