# Cannot load configuration class error spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring boot project where I am integrating my api with google calendar api.While running the application I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.api.GoogleCalApplication
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:249) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.api.GoogleCalApplication.main(GoogleCalApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:122) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7a1ebcd8
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:44) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted

2021-07-26 14:09:13.625  INFO 8492 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7bedc48a: startup date [Mon Jul 26 14:09:12 IST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
2021-07-26 14:09:13.636  WARN 8492 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7bedc48a: startup date [Mon Jul 26 14:09:12 IST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:794) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.api.GoogleCalApplication.main(GoogleCalApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

2021-07-26 14:09:13.638 ERROR 8492 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7bedc48a: startup date [Mon Jul 26 14:09:12 IST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:794) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.api.GoogleCalApplication.main(GoogleCalApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
```

Here's my controller:

```
package com.api.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.Details;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Events;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;

@Controller
public class GoogleCalController {

    private final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(GoogleCalController.class);
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "";
    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client;

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets;
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow;
    Credential credential;

    @Value("${google.client.client-id}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${google.client.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;
    @Value("${google.client.redirectUri}")
    private String redirectURI;

    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();

    final DateTime date1 = new DateTime("2020-07-26T16:30:00.000+05:30");
    final DateTime date2 = new DateTime(new Date());

    public void setEvents(Set<Event> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login/google", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public RedirectView googleConnectionStatus(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        return new RedirectView(authorize());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login/google", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "code")
    public ResponseEntity<String> oauth2Callback(@RequestParam(value = "code") String code) {
        com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events eventList;
        String message;
        try {
            TokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(redirectURI).execute();
            credential = flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, "userID");
            client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
            Events events = client.events();
            eventList = events.list("primary").setTimeMin(date1).setTimeMax(date2).execute();
            message = eventList.getItems().toString();
            System.out.println("My:" + eventList.getItems());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Exception while handling OAuth2 callback (" + e.getMessage() + ")."
                    + " Redirecting to google connection status page.");
            message = "Exception while handling OAuth2 callback (" + e.getMessage() + ")."
                    + " Redirecting to google connection status page.";
        }

        System.out.println("cal message:" + message);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public Set<Event> getEvents() throws IOException {
        return this.events;
    }

    private String authorize() throws Exception {
        AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorizationUrl;
        if (flow == null) {
            Details web = new Details();
            web.setClientId(clientId);
            web.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
            clientSecrets = new GoogleClientSecrets().setWeb(web);
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
                    Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).build();
        }
        authorizationUrl = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(redirectURI);
        System.out.println("cal authorizationUrl->" + authorizationUrl);
        return authorizationUrl.build();
    }
}
```

Here's my app starting point:

```
package com.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GoogleCalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GoogleCalApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

How to solve it?I am stuck for hours now.I have all the dependencies installed.

Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-calendar-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>google-calendar-api</name>
    <description>Demo Project for Google Calendar Api</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client -->

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-calendar -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev224-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Gmail Maven Dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev65-1.18.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
    <version>v3-rev411-1.25.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

all my client keys and secret are in resources application.properties file from where I am refering all my variables like clientId and all.While running the application I straight away get this error.How to solve it?

Comment: You are using an incompatible java version with Spring Boot 1.5. Basicaly your java version is to new.

Comment: @rude Tool, Are you kept in your application.properties file in the resources folder right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that this dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

is the one that causes the error. Try to remove it and check again. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708051/7237884) more of what that dependency is able to do, and determine if you will invest time in fixing it or just removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Either you used an old version of the dependency or application.properties file path wrongly you placed.